# Yii multisort in CArrayDataProvider

Tags: yii

Does Yii supports built in multi column sort for CArrayDataProvider(Yii 1.1.2), if yes please let me know how we can do, i'm new to yii.

Thank You.

Comment: Probably this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following (Yii API Doc example):

```
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'user',
    'sort'=>array(
        'multiSort'=>true,
        'attributes'=>array(
             'id', 'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```